# PyVISA SerialInstrument requires hard reset to connect after failure

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am working with a Keysight waveform generator and pyVisa and I notice that if my code doesn't complete successfully and ends I need to perform a hard reset of the device to attempt my code again.

I have tried resetting the device under the `__del__` method so that the device is in a known state but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using `pyvisa.resources.SerialInstrument.clear()`. Has anyone else had a problem like this and how did you solve it?

The host computer is running windows 7. PyVISA version is 1.8. After the program fails by me cancelling the python script I will try to send a simple *IDN? SCPI command to the device and I get error:

`pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.`

If I try to call pyvisa.resources.SerialInstrument.clear() on the device I get error 
`pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_INV_SETUP (-1073807302): Unable to start operation because setup is invalid (usually due to attributes being set to an inconsistent state)`.

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? what version of pyvisa? what OS?

Comment: @StephenRauch, I've edited the question answering your questions.

Comment: Ahah! I think I have found out what is causing this to happen. The device is coming up twice when I call visa.ResourceManager.list_resources(). It comes up as both a 'USB0::...' and as 'ASRL10::INSTR'. So I think the first time I ran the code it would grab the first listing and the second time it would attempt to grab that again but would end up failing and grabbing the second one.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the device was still being connected to by another instance. The cause of that was because running visa.ResourceManager().list_resources() was listing the device twice, once as a USB device and also as an ASRL.

The solution was to call `visa.ResourceManager().list_resources(query='USB?*')` to make sure that the instrument is only listed once in my results. (Alternately, I could have disabled USB or GPIB in the device settings.) Then call `device.clear()` immediately after opening the resource to make sure that the buffers were empty because at the error there might have been unread data there. This solved the problem.